# Python ttk.Combobox いったん選択した後、未選択状態にしたい。

Tags: python3, tkinter

ttk.Comboboxでいったん選択された後に、条件によって未選択状態にしたいと思います。
selection_clear()メソッドでは、未選択状態になりません。
current(-1)では、out of rangeとなってしまいます。

未選択状態に戻すにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 対応するソースとかスクリーンショットとかあった方が答えが得られやすいのでは？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selection_clear()`と`set('')`(空文字列設定)の両方を行えば、初期の状態になるのでは？

[How to control the tkinter combobox selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5235998/9014308)

> You can use the Combobox's selection_clear() method to clear the selection whenever you want. e.g
>
> ```
> inUnitsValue.selection_clear()
> ```

[How to clear text field part of ttk.Combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35233043/9014308)

> You can clear the selected value of a Combobox by setting its value to an empty string:
>
> ```
> ComboBox.set('')
> ```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。両方使うのですね。助かりました。